# how to Retrive liste of field name of a mongodb collection in java?

Tags: java, mongodb

I  have a mongodb collection, I'm looking for a method  in java to retrieve the list of fields name from this collection without data, just the fields name (for exemple : ID , AGE , DisplayName ...)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you add a sample of your data structure and how you are accessing it?

Comment: In which part are you struggling?

Answer (score 0):

Query

- group and merge all documents in 1 document with all the fields
  (you dont need this if all documents have the same schema, if all have the same (limit 1) you need as first stage and then map on "$$ROOT" not on "$docs")
- `$objectToArray` and map to get the key(the field name)

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=62921494853f039c69b0f906)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$group": {"_id": null, "docs": {"$mergeObjects": "$$ROOT"}}},
 {"$unset": ["docs._id"]},
 {"$set": 
   {"fields": 
     {"$map": {"input": {"$objectToArray": "$docs"}, "in": "$$this.k"}}}},
 {"$unset": ["docs"]}])
```